# Meteor: ArrayBuffer (FileReader result) is not passed to Meteor.method()

Tags: node.js, meteor, filereader, fs

I have this event (upload of an image file using `<input type="file">`):

```
       "change .logoBusinessBig-upload":function(event, template){

            var reader = new FileReader()

            reader.addEventListener("load", function(evt){

                var x = reader.result

                console.log(x)

                Meteor.call("saveFile", x)

            })

            reader.readAsArrayBuffer(event.currentTarget.files[0])

        }
```

and this Meteor.method()

```
       saveFile:function(file){

            console.log(file)

            var fs = Npm.require("fs")

            fs.writeFile('../../../../../public/jow.txt', file, function (err) {


                console.log("file saved")

            });

        }
```

The console.log(x) in **the event** outputs an ArrayBuffer object, while the console.log(file) in the **Meteor.method()** shows and empty {} object.

Why is that? The ArrayBuffer should have been passed to the Meteor.method()

Answer (score 10):

```js
//client.js

'change': function(event, template) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var file = event.target.files[0]; //assuming you have only 1 file
    var reader = new FileReader(); //create a reader according to HTML5 File API

    reader.onload = function(event){          
      var buffer = new Uint8Array(reader.result) // convert to binary
      Meteor.call('saveFile',buffer);
    }

    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); //read the file as arraybuffer
}

//server.js

'saveFile': function(buffer){
    fs.writeFile('/location',new Buffer(buffer),function(error){...});
}
```

You can't save to /public folder, this triggers a reload

Comment: you just saved me man! i've been researching for this for whole 2 weeks already! hahaha thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Client-server communication via methods in Meteor uses the DDP protocol, which only supports [EJSON-able](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/ejson) data-types and does not allow the transmission of more complex object like your ArrayBuffer, which is why you don't see it on the server.

I suggest you [read the file as a binary string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader.readAsBinaryString), send it to your method like that and then manipulate it (either via an ArrayBuffer or by some other means) once it's on the server.

Comment: readAsBinaryString is deprecated... can i use DDP to transfer a client image to my /public folder?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that `EJSON` will encode typed arrays as base64 strings it doesn't matter if using `EJSON` or `DateURL` - they are equally inefficient (increasing bandwidth use by 30%).

So this:

```
reader.onload = function(event){          
  var buffer = new Uint8Array(reader.result) // convert to binary
  Meteor.call('saveFile',buffer); // will convert to EJSON/base64
}

reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file); //read the file as arraybuffer
```

is equivalent to

```
reader.onload = function(event){          
  Meteor.call('saveFile',reader.result);
}

reader.readAsDataURL(file); //read the file DataURL (base 64)
```

The last version is a line shorter on the client side, but will add a line on the server side when you unpack the file to trim it of the mime-type prefix, typically something like

```
new Buffer(dataURI.replace(/^data:.{1,20}\/.{1,30};base64,/, ''), 'base64');
```

## The alternative: XHR

So neither is really more efficient. If you want to to save on bandwidth, try doing this bit using XHR, which natively suppports all the binary types (`File`, `ArrayBuffer`, `Blob`). You might need to handle it outside of Meteor, perhaps as a small Express app with a route handled by a front-end proxy like NginX.